# extract the twitter profile header information

Tags: php

need some help with retrieving information+Profile pic from twitter using php , i wanted to extract the profile information of some public twitter profiles for example

https://twitter.com/#!/NatureMagazine

If you go to the link this is the information,

*Nature Magazine 
@NatureMagazine
International weekly journal of science. Research coverage here. For News/Comment, please see @NatureNews. (most tweets from @noahWG or @roobina)*

I have the CURL functionality in place so getting the source of the page is not an issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

example Facebook share

Comment: Why don't you simply use twitter api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to check the twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs

For example if you want to get the profile image of @NatureMagazine in the biggest format:

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=naturemagazine&size=bigger

Comment: Guys , i have got what i was looking for..just wanted to share.. please check this link